# Select certain columns, fill missing values in these columns with the average of columns with not-na values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe df as follows:

```
         date      value        pred1        pred2        pred3
0   2021-9-19  3613.9663          NaN          NaN          NaN
1   2021-9-26  3613.0673          NaN          NaN          NaN
2   2021-10-3  3568.1668          NaN          NaN          NaN
3  2021-10-10  3592.1666  3631.411799          NaN          NaN
4  2021-10-17  3572.3662  3637.792491  3677.656329          NaN
5  2021-10-24  3582.6036  3678.800911  3707.926324  3712.669694
6  2021-10-31  3547.3361  3731.336899  3735.695071  3733.021293
7   2021-11-7  3491.5677  3749.422639  3743.507496          NaN
8  2021-11-14  3539.1002  3737.851787          NaN          NaN
9  2021-11-21  3560.3734          NaN          NaN          NaN
```

Suppose for columns `pred1`, `pred2` and `pred3`, except that all these columns are `NaN`s, if it has one `non-null` value, I will populate the other columns with that value, and if it has two or more `non-null` values, I will use the average of `non-null` values to fill null values of other columns.

For example, for the row with date `2021-10-10`, I will populate `pred2` and `pred3` with the value of `pred1`; for the row with date `2021-10-17`, I will populate `pred3` with the mean of `pred1` and `pred2` on that day; The same logic will apply to `2021-11-7` and `2021-11-14`.

The expected result:

```
         date      value        pred1        pred2        pred3
0   2021-9-19  3613.9663          NaN          NaN          NaN
1   2021-9-26  3613.0673          NaN          NaN          NaN
2   2021-10-3  3568.1668          NaN          NaN          NaN
3  2021-10-10  3592.1666  3631.411799  3631.411799  3631.411799
4  2021-10-17  3572.3662  3637.792491  3677.656329  3657.724410
5  2021-10-24  3582.6036  3678.800911  3707.926324  3712.669694
6  2021-10-31  3547.3361  3731.336899  3735.695071  3733.021293
7   2021-11-7  3491.5677  3749.422639  3743.507496     2.957571
8  2021-11-14  3539.1002  3737.851787  3737.851787  3737.851787
9  2021-11-21  3560.3734          NaN          NaN          NaN
```

Anyone could help to deal this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What is your main goal? You have been asking one question at a time. Meaning we are solving intermediary questions rather than the main problem. look at [`xy problem`](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Sorry. Let me explain: I am trying to make a new dataset to train a new model from the results of a time series rolling forecast. The original dataset is a data frame that includes: `date, value, 20211003, 20211010, 20211017` these columns. The last three columns are rolling forecasts for `value` column. By reshaping `pred1, pred2 pred3`, I want to take these three columns as a new `X`, and to predict `y`, which is `value` column. I'm also not sure if it makes sense to do this, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure it does. It only seems that we have been solving intermediate steps, rather than tackling the problem at once. Your code might be slow since there is alot of `apply` functions used. Probably if the question had been fully defined from the beginning, a function to solve the problem would have been provided by some of the python wizards here

Comment: I thought that the community wanted our question to solve one problem, so I divided a slightly large, complex problem into smaller ones.

Comment: Thats fine. If at all the steps given does solve the problem at hand, you are good. I was just curious on what you were trying to solve since you asked almost 3 questions on a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.iloc[:,2:].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()), axis = 1)
 
         pred1        pred2        pred3
0          NaN          NaN          NaN
1          NaN          NaN          NaN
2          NaN          NaN          NaN
3  3631.411799  3631.411799  3631.411799
4  3637.792491  3677.656329  3657.724410
5  3678.800911  3707.926324  3712.669694
6  3731.336899  3735.695071  3733.021293
7  3749.422639  3743.507496  3746.465068
8  3737.851787  3737.851787  3737.851787
9          NaN          NaN          NaN
```